# Commands to open tabs and splits of multiple files

Tags: file, split, tabs, command, multiple-columns

Opening files is a very common task. I usually start Vim with `-O` option, so many files are vertically split opened at once.

Is there any similar way to, once inside Vim, do the same for tabs? I mean something like `:tabe -O file file ...`. Or at the same tab, like `:vsp -O file file ...`?

Answer (score 0):

yes 
e.g

`:args file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt|:tab sall`

open the 3 files in 3 different tabs

there are also alternative methods, more information [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Load_multiple_files_with_a_single_command#)